# MVC5 Razor view String.Join reversing order on each iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, concatenation

I am populating my view model in an `ASP.NET MVC5` project using the following `LINQ` statement in my controller, using a `List<string>` to hold the address lines so these can be concatenated in my view.

```
var model = db.School
              .Where(s => s.IsClosed == false)
              .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
              .Select(s => new SchoolIndex
              {
                  SchoolCode = s.Code,
                  School = s.Name,
                  LocalAuthority = s.LocalAuthority,
                  IsClosed = s.lIsClosed,
                  AddressLines = new List<string>() {
                        s.Address1,
                        s.Address2,
                        s.Address3,
                        s.Address4,
                        s.Address5,
                        s.Postcode
                  }
              }).ToPagedList(Page, 50);
```

Within my view I am using `String.Join` to concatenate the address lines onto one line in a table cell along with the `LINQ` query to remove any null or blank address lines.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var school in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(s => school.SchoolCode)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(s => school.School)
                <div class="school-address">
                    @String.Join(",", school.AddressLines
                                            .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(s => school.LocalAuthority)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(s => school.IsClosed)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

However, my results are not displayed as expected and I am getting results similar to:

```
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Postcode, Address5, Address4, Address3, Address2, Address1
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Postcode, Address5, Address4, Address3, Address2, Address1
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Postcode, Address5, Address4, Address3, Address2, Address1
```

The expected results are:

```
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5, Postcode
```

How can I fix this so all the addresses are displayed correctly? I'm guessing I need to specify an `OrderBy` using the `Index` value of the `List<string>` though I am unsure on the syntax.

**UPDATE:**
When debugging the controller creating the model the `List<string>` in my view model isn't being populated in the order specified, sometimes it is correct though it looks to be random.

Comment: I don't think String.Join() is causing that. Check what actual ordering contains your collection after DB select.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I have updated my question with expected results and note that my view model is not being populated as I intended.

Comment: When you attach a debugger with a breakpoint to the line in the controller 's.Address1,' is it containing "Address1" each time? I suspect that the result from db.School is changing each time.

Comment: The data in the underlying table is correct, it's just that the List<string> is not being populated in the order that has been specified for each row of data. I would have expected that each data column would always be in the same index of the List<string> rather than random for each row of data. Perhaps this is a limitation or a misunderstanding of how list initialization works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably EF select doesn't save ordering you are trying to achieve. Try this workaround:

```
// change AddressLines definition to such:
public class AddressLines 
{
     // your other properties
     // ..
     public string Address1 {get;set;}
     public string Address2 {get;set;}
     public string Address3 {get;set;}
     public string Address4 {get;set;}
     public string Address5 {get;set;}
     public string PostCode{get;set;}

     public IEnumerable<String> AddressLines
     {
         get 
         {
             return new [] {
                    this.Address1,
                    this.Address2,
                    this.Address3,
                    this.Address4,
                    this.Address5,
                    this.Postcode
              };
         }
     }
}
```

Then modify the select:

```
   var model = db.School
          .Where(s => s.IsClosed == false)
          .OrderBy(s => s.Name)
          .Select(s => new SchoolIndex
          {
              SchoolCode = s.Code,
              School = s.Name,
              LocalAuthority = s.LocalAuthority,
              IsClosed = s.lIsClosed,
              Address1 = s.Address1,
              Address2 = s.Address2,
              Address3 = s.Address3,
              Address4 = s.Address4,
              Address5 = s.Address5,
              Postcode = s.Postcode
              }
          }).ToPagedList(Page, 50);
```

This way AddressLines collection will be formed after actual select, and should have correct order.

Comment: Thanks, as an interim I am using this as my solution though I'd be interested to understand why the List initialization is not working as I expected.

Comment: I would make an educated guess, that EF simply creates select query, and after puts it into array, so ordering depends on actual SQL server response, which can be unpredictable. Try profiling SQL query generated by EF, to see the actual reason.